# QGIS - digitising polyline on Google maps base

Tags: qgis, qgis-openlayers-plugin, digitizing

I'm displaying a Google Street map via the Openlayers plugin and hand-digitising a route to find out its length. As I pan the map the digitized line keeps shifting slightly on the basemap. I'm using the project projection of British National Grid (EPSG27700) with on the fly projection turned on.

What is causing this problem? How do I know if my digitized line is actually in the right place?

Comment: Can you provide screen shots of what you are seeing?

Comment: You need to use Web Mercator if you want to use background maps from OpenLayers plugin.